# Tomcat not able to find Microsoft SQL driver class

Tags: sql-server, tomcat

**Tomcat version** - apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19

I am trying to connect my spring application with microsoft sql database.

**driverClassName**=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLserverDriver

**Maven dependency** -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
```

This jar is available in the generated war file and i have also placed the jar in the lib folder of the tomcat but i'm still getting the following error when i try to deploy my application on Tomcat -

> Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLserverDriver'
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLserverDriver

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your config. The driver class is named

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

not

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLserverDriver
................................^...........
```

Comment: :-| Thanks a lot! I checked it a hundred times but skipped this somehow.

Comment: You are welcome. @Avisha if this is the answer, please mark your question answered.

Comment: I can't see any difference ?!

Comment: @Noris yes it's hard to see, but the `s` after the upper case `SQL`  must be upper case too: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQL[S]erverDriver`